# passing multiple parameters via GET methode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to send three parameters through get methode in javascript.I am using

```
window.location = 'example.php?Appno=' + AppNo +"code="+RCode+"subcode="+RSubCode;
```

but i am getting combined form in Appno variable.How to seperate this.?Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to put & after the end of value. AppNo + "&"+"code=";;;

Answer (score 1):

You have to add & between parameters.
For example:

```
window.location = 'example.php?Appno=' + AppNo +"&code="+RCode+"&subcode="+RSubCode;
```